# category of semi-simple modules is not closed under extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of left semi-simple $R-$modules.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the example of $\mathcal{C}$ is not closed under extension?(i.e. Given $A,B$ semi-simple modules, there is $X$ not a semi-simple module s.t. $0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$ is $R$ left module exact sequence.) I have thought of $Z_6$ over $Z_6$. $Z_6\cong Z_2\times Z_3$. Now $0\to Z_2\to Z_2\times Z_3\to Z_3\to 0$ is an extension of $Z_2,Z_3$ as $Z_6$ module. I do not see other obvious possible extensions.

Ref. Auslander, Reiten, Representation Theory of Artin Algebras.

Comment: What examples of not semi-simple modules do you know?

Comment: @AlexB. That is the part that I have not seen so far. I knew some basic semi-simple rings as product of fields. Then modules over semi-simple rings are semi-simple. So I think I basically have no idea about non semi simples modules.

Comment: The case $R = \mathbb{Z}$ is already instructive. Try figuring out what the simple and semisimple modules are.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan All simple modules over $Z$ are of form $Z/(p)$ with $p$ prime. Semi-simple ones are built up from products of $Z/(p)$. So I guess I could consider $0\to (2)\to Z/(4)\to Z/(2)\to 0$ where first arrow is by canonical injection and second arrow is by standard projection. Clearly $Z/(4)$ is not semi-simple or it will be $Z/(2)\times Z/(2)$. Is this correct? So in order to look for not closed under extensions, one has to look for non-semi simple rings? Maybe this is dumb, are you implying over semi-simple rings, the extension property is closed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think over semi-simple rings, the extension property is closed by $Ext$ group applied to any module being 0 as every module is both projective and injective over semi-simple rings. So extensions are always trivial. So semi-simpleness is closed under extension.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a lot.